# Search an Entity Model for an Entity By Primary Key Value?

Tags: c#-4.0, entity-framework-4

Is there any way of finding out if an objects exists in your model or data source simply by supplying a primary key. A unique key that should only refer to a record or entity that exists in your database.

i.e pass in a GUID and the model will tell you if it has anything by that uses the same key value.

Using EF 4.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My two cents: Haven't tried it but seems to be along the the right track from what I was looking for:

[How to get an Entity Framework Anyways - Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/322275/Get-an-Entity-Framework-Object-anyway/)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean in your model or data source, but here is an example that returns null if it does not exist.

```
public MyType GetEntityByEntityID(Int32 _entityID)
{
    using (var ctx = new MyEntities())
    {
        return ctx.MyTypes.Where(c => c.EntityID == _entityID).FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

Comment: model is commonly used to refer to your data source or data access point or data context. so 'ctx' above would be your model. I asking about finding keys by their primary keys at a more general level, i.e the database omly has a key to go on and that's it. The Database will have to query all its tables for that key, thats what I am trying to figure out. There is the 'GetObjectByKey' method, that might be worth looking into.